# How to add text in a php page

Tags: php, redirect

I have a PHP code to redirect on other domain, this one

```
<?php
 header("Location: {$_GET['url']}");
 echo 'You are redirecting to ... page';
 sleep(5);
?>
```

And it works like when i add any external url at the end of **http://my-domain.com/URL.php?url=** it just redirects to external domain in this case let's take google:

> http//my-domain.com/URL.php?url=http//www.google.com

and it just redirects directly on the page after 5 seconds load but i want to show a php page with some decoration like a loading icon and some text like `"Please wait while you're being redirected to http://www.google.com"`

Also i tried `echo 'Please wait while you're being redirected';` But it just redirects directly to external domain without showing the message.

Comment: (1) The `sleep()` function waits *server-side*, not *client-side*.  (2) When the browser sees a redirect header, it doesn't even bother to look at the content.  Because there shouldn't be any.  Because it's a redirect.  If you want to display a page, then display a page.  Include in that page client-side code to perform the redirect after your client-side delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want javascript to do the timeout, you can add the refresh timer to the php header function:

```
header("Refresh: 5; url={$_GET['url']}");
```

Or go super old school and spit this out in the html:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url='. $_GET['url'] .'">';
```

Edit: I'd like to mention if you go old school, be sure to sanitize the url (dont just pass the GET variable out blindly like the above sample).

Comment: PS: and yes, remove `sleep(5);`

Comment: That would be an entirely different question regarding html and css ;)

Comment: ok i will check it :) btw look at this https://i.imgur.com/CjG2IqM.jpg i made some changes...

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
<?php
echo "Please wait...";
echo sprintf('
   <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    },2000);

   </script>
');
```